# convert URLDecoder.decode(temp, "UTF-8") to php

Tags: java, php, servlets, urldecode

I am converting a Java Servlet web application to php.

How should I convert the following Java commands to php?

```
String temp = request.getParameter("q");
String temp2 = URLDecoder.decode(temp, "UTF-8");
```

Any help will greatly appreciated...

EDIT:

This is client code:

```
 var myJSONText = playlist.serialize();

  $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       url : "playlisthandler.php",
       data : {
           "q" : encodeURIComponent(myJSONText)
       },
       success : function(response) { ... },
       error : function(response) { ... },
       dataType : "json"
   });
```

Are you saying that the encodeURIComponent is redundant?

Comment: This is a rather strange question. The servlet `request.getParameter()` already by default decodes it based on the request character encoding. The need to do so would indicate that the client is actually double-encoding the query string which in turn means that the problem needs to be fixed on the client side so that it's encoding it only once. The same applies to PHP by the way, if the request parameter is properly encoded by the client, there should be no need to manually decode it once again in the server afterwards.

Comment: This is client code:

  var myJSONText = playlist.serialize();

  $.ajax({
       type : 'POST',
       url : "playlisthandler.php",
       data : {
           "q" : encodeURIComponent(myJSONText)
       },
       success : function(response) { ... },
       error : function(response) { ... },
       dataType : "json"
   });

Are you saying that the encodeURIComponent is redundant?

Comment: jQuery already does that, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have the need to do so. The `request.getParameter()` in servlet API and the `$_REQUEST` (and inherently also `$_GET` and `$_POST`) in PHP **already** do that based on the request character encoding. The need to do so indicates that the client side is doing it wrong by double-encoding the query string components.

As per your code you're indeed explicitly encoding the query string while jQuery already does that under the covers:

```
data : { "q" : encodeURIComponent(myJSONText) },
```

Remove the `encodeURIComponent()` call so that the `data` becomes `{ "q" : myJSONText }`. jQuery will already take care that it will be URL-encoded. The `encodeURIComponent()` is only necessary when you're using plain vanilla `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$paramValue = urldecode($_GET['q']);
```

Comment: The php equivalent of `URLDecoder.decode(temp, "UTF-8");` has already been called on the php `$_GET` array (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)